# How to update an array of object for multiple documents in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm trying to update an array of objects for multiple documents.
I've tried using $addToSet and $push but every time its updating only the last found document.

```
db.getCollection("test").update(
  { _id: { $in: [ObjectId("string"), ObjectId("string")] } },
  {
    $addToSet: {
      my_array: {
        a_id: ObjectId("string"),
        b: "$_id",
        c: Date.now(),
        d: true,
        e: "$b_id"
      }
    }
  },
  { multi: true }
);
```

Sample Data :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "last_name" : "test1",
    "email" : null,
    "first_name" : "test1",
    "mobile" : "+910000000001",
    "created_at" : 1636353942250,
    "updated_at" : 1636353942250,
    "my_array" : [
    {
        a_id : ObjectId(),
        b : ObjectId(),
        c : Date.now(),
        d : true,
        e : ObjectId()
    },
    {
        a_id : ObjectId(),
        b : ObjectId(),
        c : Date.now(),
        d : true,
        e : ObjectId()
    },
    {
        a_id : ObjectId(),
        b : ObjectId(),
        c : Date.now(),
        d : true,
        e : ObjectId()
    },
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "last_name" : "test",
    "email" : null,
    "first_name" : "test",
    "mobile" : "+910000000000",
    "created_at" : 1636353942250,
    "updated_at" : 1636353942250,
    "my_array" : [
    {
        a_id : ObjectId(),
        b : ObjectId(),
        c : Date.now(),
        d : true,
        e : ObjectId()
    },
    {
        a_id : ObjectId(),
        b : ObjectId(),
        c : Date.now(),
        d : true,
        e : ObjectId()
    },
    {
        a_id : ObjectId(),
        b : ObjectId(),
        c : Date.now(),
        d : true,
        e : ObjectId()
    },
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to do this is Node using mongoose.
How can I achieve this without using for loop or if there is any other optimized way?

Comment: Can you provide sample data to reproduce? Thanks

Comment: Added sample data.  @YongShun